# Cannot get Ember action to bubble

Tags: ember.js

I have spent a lot of time trying to implement what ought to be a simple thing in Ember: bubbling an action from a component to the application controller. The docs say that in order to propogate an action then all I need to do is declare the action when I declare the template:

```
{{#if isLoggedIn}}
  {{menu-bar action="authenticate"}}
{{/if}}
```

...and then send the action from the component (which is nested in the login route):

```
authenticate: function() {
  //code omitted for brevity
  this.sendAction('authenticate');
}
```

...which should be received by the application route:

```
  user: Ember.inject.service(),
  isLoggedIn: false,
  actions: {
    authenticate: function(){
      console.log('authenticated!');
      this.set('isLoggedIn', this.get('user').isLoggedIn());
    }
  }
```

but it isn't. And I'm wasting a lot of time trying to work out why.

I'm sure it's really obvious but if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you setup demo on ember-twiddle.com or emberjs.jsbin.com? In which template do you use `{{menu-bar authenticate="authenticate"}}`?

Comment: Hi, I'll try and set something up in JSBin although I've never done it before. The menu-bar gets rendered in the application.hbs template, but the component is rendered in the login.hbs template (which is rendered in application.hbs's outlet)

Comment: It would help a lot in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the application controller isn't supposed to catch bubbled actions, the application *route* is. For the life of me I can't find the relevant section in the guides any more, but actions don't bubble through controllers, they bubble through routes. The first place an action usually goes (and is true in your case) is the relevant controller. In your case, you don't want the controller to catch it you want it to bubble. However, if an action isn't caught by a controller it bubbles to that controller's route. From there, it *does not* bubble to parent controllers, it only bubbles to parent routes.

For instance, let's say you had the following routes:

```
this.route('books', function() {
    this.route('book', { path: '/:book_id' });
});
```

The bubbling order would be as such:

1. Component
2. Book controller
3. Book route
4. Books route
5. Application route

TL;DR: Catch your action in the application route, not controller. If I can find the guide on action bubbling, I'll edit my answer and link to it.

Comment: Actually, the route was the first place I tried to catch it. I used "ember generate route application" to create the route and then added the logic in the above controller but it still doesn't log 'authenticated' to the console or update 'isLoggedIn' in Ember inspector. I think the section on ActionBubbling can be found in http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling but it doesn't appear in later guides.

Comment: Daniel Kmak had an answer that he deleted that suggested specifying an action to the `sendAction()` method. Can you try `this.sendAction("authenticate")` in combination with my suggested solution? I believe if you don't specify the action in the call, you have to use `action="authenticate"` in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but no those changes haven't worked either. Can I just check - the application route can be called application.js, provided it's in the routes folder?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that I had put the action="authenticate" on the wrong component! Apologies to GJK and Daniel Kmak for wasting your time trying to solve that one but it seems that I had just got mixed up.

Comment: That's why I wanted demo. :D Good luck.

Comment: No problem. Such things happen too all of us.